# Alter cell size of gdal_grid command

Tags: gdal, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I'm using the below command in the GDAL commandline to grid a shapefile using IDW interpolation

```
gdal_grid -a invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=1.0 -of GTiff C:/users/public/test.shp C:/users/public/test.tiff
```

This works fine, but I'd like the cell-size to be smaller. I tried adding `-outsize 0.5 0.5` to the command but it made no difference.

How can I set the each tile of the raster output to be 0.5 x 0.5m ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#cmdoption-gdal_grid-tr):

```
-tr <xres> <yres>
    Set output file resolution (i.e. the pixel size).
```

Note you need to specify `-txe` and `-tye` as well.

Or specify a larger [`-outsize`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#cmdoption-gdal_grid-outsize):

```
-outsize <xsize ysize>
    Set the size of the output file in pixels and lines 
   (i.e the number of rows and columns, the higher these values, 
   the smaller the pixel size). Note that -outsize cannot be used with -tr
```